# Xamarin binding EventHandler

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

How can I bind event handler from xaml to ViewModel
in my xamal:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding SecondName , Mode=TwoWay}"  Focused="{Binding FocusedEventhandler}" Completed="{Binding Compleated}">
```

How can i get that event handler actions in my viewModel?

Comment: For which event are you looking for `Focused` or `Completed`?

Comment: What you need to do is turn your event into a command the view model can hook up to. There are several examples out there. Take a look [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/) for one example.

Comment: @Arvindraja I am looking for both

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
public class TestViewModel 
{    
    public ICommand FocusedEventhandler { get; private set; }   
    public TestViewModel()
    {     
        FocusedEventhandler = new Command(async () => await ShowContactList());   
    }  

    async Task ShowContactList()
    {   
        //your code here
    }   
}
```

Call your ViewModel from your page

```
public partial class TestPage: ContentPage {  
public AddContact() {  
    InitializeComponent();  
    BindingContext = new TestViewModel();  
}
```

This is just overview, to give you an idea how we can do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Arvindraja, I have tried same way but I got response like 
"Unhandled Exception:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 16:95. Property Focused is not found or does not have an accessible getter"

Comment: here is my way 
`<Entry Text="{Binding SecondName , Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Enter your second name" Focused="{Binding FocusedEventhandler}">

</Entry>`

Comment: here is viewmodel
`public ICommand FocusedEventhandler { get; private set; }
        async Task ShowContactList()
        {
            //your code here
        }

 public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            InitializeCommands();
        }
private void InitializeCommands()
        {
            TextChanging = new Command(() => { EntryTextChanging(); });
            FocusedEventhandler = new Command(async () => await ShowContactList());
        }`

Comment: files are two big , unable to post

Comment: Just do some r&d. There is so many article available out there regarding the same. No one guess your exact issue except guiding you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old now, but I believe the proper answer to this question is now to use Behaviors to map from Event Handler to Behavior to Command, in the case that the UI Control's XAML property, e.g. SearchBar.TextChanged, expects an event handler. Please see the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating

and here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/